# How to get order details in paid membership pro wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get order details like

> invoice number,
>
> Membership Date Of Purchase,
>
> Payment Method,
>
> Card Number Details

In Paid Membership Pro Wordpress Plugin

Here is [documentation](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/).

I have tried Following Code.

```
<?php
 echo "<pre>";
if (is_user_logged_in() && function_exists('pmpro_hasMembershipLevel') && pmpro_hasMembershipLevel()) {
    global $current_user;
    global $wpdb, $pmpro_invoice, $pmpro_msg, $pmpro_msgt;

    $current_user->membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($current_user);

}
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: What is it echoing out currently? And what are you expecting it to echo out?

Comment: I want to get order details like invoice number,Membership Date Of Purchase,Payment Method, Card Number Details here is builtin  function for membership_level  similarly there must be the order details function but I didn't get read the documentation and please help me in it.  https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/

Comment: What currently echos out?